# how to migration from visual c++ 6.0 to visual c++ 2010 , from 32bit to 64bit app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, migration, visual-c++-2010

i must migrate a large project from visual c++ 6.0 to visual c++ 2010 and from windows xp  sp2 32bit to windows 7 64bit app.
about my project : C/C++ Objective ,not use library , the project build in windows xp 32 bit and visual c++ 6.0 ide .there are 2.2 milion line of code 
what approach to this?
please help me!

Comment: (1) Create a new Visual C++ 2010 project; (2) Set the warning level to /W4; (3) Add all of the source files to the Visual C++ 2010 project; (4) Build Debug; (5) Fix the errors and warnings.

Comment: What libraries are used? What kind of project? How many lines of code?

Comment: C/C++ Objective ,not use library , the project build in windows xp 32 bit and visual c++ 6.0.there are 2.2 milion line of code

Comment: How are you going to find the places where 64 bits are going to break your code?  Example:   "int count;" will likely continue to be 32 bits, but in the 64 bit world you may have more than 4 billion counted things.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/411798/120163. I hope you have good testing capabilities.

Comment: .... Do you mean "Objective-C/C++"? Apparantly not, but "C/C++ Objective" is a very strange phrase. What do you mean by that?

Comment: You need advice on how to tackle 2.2 million lines of code known to work only on a compiler that is so old that it wasn't C++98 compliant and converting to 64-bit and having no clue how to get started?  Run man, run!  Or give it a whack by having VS2010 convert the VC6 projects and see what hits the fan.  Then sit down with your supervisor and set realistic goals and schedules.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list-o-links to MS docs that are as good a starting point as anything:

- [64-Bit Programming with Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2k70f3s.aspx)
- [Common Visual C++ 64-bit Migration Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2e7499.aspx)
- [General Porting Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384190.aspx)
- [Migration Tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384214.aspx)

On top of all that you may need to deal with some language changes that are unrelated to 64-bit migration, such as the change in how variables declared in `for` loops are handled. The `/Zc:forScope` and `/Zc:wchar_t` options might help with some of those.