# Error at read( ) in C code after switching from 34-bit to 64-bit machine

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit

I have had to switch some functional c code over from a 32 bit machine to a 64 bit machine. I have found some useful links on how to do that (ex. [Converting 32-bit Application Into 64-bit Application in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411798/converting-32-bit-application-into-64-bit-application-in-c)) and so far I have replaced all instances of 'long' with 'int' but I am still encountering problems.

The program compiles but when I run it, it gets stuck. When I force it to close I get a Seg. fault. I have found the exact line where the program gets hung up (i.e. it gets to SheilaTestPoint1 but not SheilaTestPoint2).

```
    fprintf(stderr, "SheilaTestPoint1");
    check = read(fpheading, &header, 8);
    fprintf(stderr, "SheilaTestPoint2");
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Thank you!!

Comment: I'm guessing that the 8 is the size of `header`, but that may have changed. You should do `sizeof(header)`. But then, if the actual file contains 8 bytes, then you should change the `header` definition to be exactly 8 bytes.

Comment: This is not answerable without seeing the allegedly problematic code in context.

Comment: @rodrigo - you are moving towards a good point, which is that if "header" is a structure it's internal format & packing may have changed, quite possibly no longer matching the data in the file.

Comment: I'm curious what `read` is. Is it POSIX `read(2)`? `fpheading` looks like a `FILE*` but `open(2)` accepts a file descriptor `int`. Wouldn't you be getting an `EFAULT` rather than a segfault?

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. fpheading is a file handle so it is an int. Also, header is defined in the program earlier as: char header[20];